# Chi-Squared for demonstrating confounding in Logistic regression (or not...)

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, chi-squared-test, confounding

I am using logistic regression for inference and classification, using data from 190 X-rays/subjects. We want to see if certain X-ray measurements could predict development of a disease (Case vs Control) later on.

I want to understand the effects of confounding on my Logistic regression predictions.

I have an important **known confounder**: the position of the patient during the X-ray capture (Sitting/Standing, 0,1). Since this is clinical retrospective data*, there is some randomness to as to who is Sitting/Standing. But there is a definite bias towards case patients having more X-rays while sitting:

```
        Control  Case                
Sitting: 13.16% 48.42% 
Standing 25.26% 13.16%
```

I know that some (not all) of my measurements are VERY influenced by the Sit/stand condition.

To better demonstrate the confounding effect of Sit/Stand, I have obtained the predicted classes for my data. I have then **obtained a binary variable for each sample on whether the Prediction was correct (1) or incorrect (0)**.
I figured, one way I could look at the relationship to my confounder (Sit/Stand) is with a Chi-Square test, since Correct/Incorrect + Sit/Stand are both binary:

*Univariate LogReg--> Prediction---> Chi-Square (Prediction Correct/incorrect ~ Sit/Stand) ---> P-value*

Testing with X-ray **measurements I know are strongly related to Sit/Stand** (measurement 1) generates a very small Chi-Square P-value. I am interpreting this as Sit/Stand exerting its effects on model predictions.
Similarly, using X-ray features we know are NOT influenced by Sit/Stand (measurement_22), generates a large P-value:

```
XR-measurement_1                      XR-measurement_22 
Chi-Sqr p-value: 0.0002               Chi-Sqr p-value: 0.21 
Chi-Square Statistic: 13.44           13.47 Chi-Square Statistic: 0.65
```

---

This is an idea I came up with. So it cannot be very good... However, I am struggling to find ways to make inferences about how my predictions are being confounded. I feel like trying to look at the attributes of correctly and incorrectly classified samples could help me understand where Sit/Stand is confounding my X-ray measurements.
I think the model struggles with Cases who are standing (since 2/3 of cases are sitting)

- Is this an unnecessarily complicated way of demonstrating
  confounding?
- Is it even demonstrating confounding?
- Are there better tools to explore this?
- Is this a dead end, and I should just finish 'Applied Logistic Regression by David Hosmer JR.'?**

*We are studying a rare disease... Its very unlikely we will be able to prospectively collect data. So the Sit/Stand issue is unlikely to go away.

**I am slowly making my way through: Applied Logistic Regression by David Hosmer JR. But so far I've just read about confounding observation using coefficients/odds ratios/model summaries.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer now, but why not just add "position" and interactions with other variables, to the logistic model?

Comment: Adding 'position' to the LogReg model does have the expected effect. But the above approach appeals because it uses the prediction results. I'm skeptical about the predictions being useful. Ideally I would adjust for position, and then do ChiSqr on the prediction accuracy ~ 'position'. Im hoping this would show whether 'position' is still erroneously driving the prediction results(but this violates independence assumption). I also am interested whether the comparing the ChiSqr statistic could give an impression of the magnitude confounding between IVs. But open to this is all redundant!